# Search for threads with at least one of the provided label ids

Tags: php, fetch, gmail-api

I am programming a function to query the PHP gmail API. This function will execute in parallel to another query which will search threads stored on our system. The purpose of this is to ensure all the results are found even if a thread was not synced due to it being very old or missed by an expired history token.

I am using $service->users_threads->listUsersThreads('me', $opt_param); to search the threads and I am also using the query pram to help filter the results. I can do a variety of things thanks to the syntax here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

A sample of my query:

```
-in:chats after:2016-01-28 before:2017-06-23 label:{city-and-colour} (l:(^ss_sp|^ss_co)) is:starred
```

But searching for threads with label_id in (Label_1, Label_2, Label_3) as an OR condition is proving to be difficult. The function can accept a parameter labelIds which will do an AND search for the label id provided but this is not desired. By doing label:{...} in the text query I can find the labels but I cannot find the bridge to go from the data retrieved about the label to the string required to search using this method.

Can anyone help me search for threads containing one or more of the provided label ids without executing multiple searches for each individual label?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no feature regarding this but as a workaround you will have to use `q` parameter and make a multiple label filter with `OR/AND`. Or, since you want to filter by multiple `labelID`, you have to multiple request for each `labelID`.